Linux TC, HTB: Is there defined behavior when the sum of class ceil rates exceeds total interface ceil rate?
I am trying to shape traffic using HTB, and I ran into some weird behaviour in my tests. In my tests, I have one sender and two receivers, and my first goal was to test how bandwidth allocation behaves by default, and then how it behaves when shaped with tc. The test case with which I ran into the weird part is the following: the sender has 1Gbit/s max bandwidth on its interface, and the ceil rates on the connections are 1Gbit/s (receiver 1) and 700Mbit/s (receiver 2), respectively (Note: It is on purpose that they exceed the interface max.). For testing purposes, I used 1Mbit/s as minimum guaranteed rate, because I didn't want to modify the default behaviour too much. The test has two scenarios, and they only differ in the fact of who starts receiving data first.
First scenario: for 15 seconds, the sender constantly sends some data to receiver 2. After that, the sender starts sending data to receiver 1. This results in less bandwidth for receiver 1 than when it is the only one asking for data (this is of course rather obvious), and thus in more time to deliver data (more precisely, 2GB worth of data). Pretty much expected.
Second scenario: I do the same thing as in the first scenario, but this time receiver 1 is the one that starts receiving from the beginning (i.e. the first 15 seconds), and receiver 2 joins in later on. This resulted in a much larger increase in time it take to receive the data for receiver 2.
To give more context, for receiver 1 the time increase was around 30%, while for receiver 2 the time increase was almost 200%. I did, of course, measure the time it took to transfer the data when no interference was happening from the other receiver, for both connections, the 1Gbit/s and the 700Mbit/s one.
My main question here is: Why is this increase so asymmetric? I expected the interference of another connection to be the same, or very very similar, but I got a drastic increase. It seems as tho the faster connection was favoured, even if I didn't tell tc to favour it. Is it just because the first connection is stronger, and then favoured possibly by TCP below? I was wondering is there some documented behaviour for this case, I searched for a bit and didn't seem to find any explicit explanation of what happens when HTB gets overlimitted.
For more context, here is the tc configuration used:
#!/bin/bash

INTERFACE="enp39s0"

sudo tc qdisc del dev $INTERFACE root 2>/dev/

sudo tc qdisc add dev $INTERFACE root handle 1: htb default 30

sudo tc class add dev $INTERFACE parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 1gbit ceil 1gbit
sudo tc class add dev $INTERFACE parent 1:1 classid 1:10 htb rate 1mbit ceil 1gbit
sudo tc class add dev $INTERFACE parent 1:1 classid 1:20 htb rate 1mbit ceil 700mbit

sudo tc filter add dev $INTERFACE protocol ip parent 1: prio 1 u32 match ip dst 172.31.3.53 flowid 1:10
sudo tc filter add dev $INTERFACE protocol ip parent 1: prio 1 u32 match ip dst 172.31.10.151 flowid 1:20

sudo tc -s qdisc show dev $INTERFACE
sudo tc -s class show dev $INTERFACE

echo "HTB configuration with capped bandwidth applied to $INTERFACE"

Thank you very much for any help with this, apologies if the question was long, I tried to give the most succinct context possible!
